# Serve website from different directory based on URL string parameter

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, url

I would like to learn if I can serve the website from 2 different versions according to URL string parameters.

**Example:**

- I have two installs on my server: domain.com/website-1/ & domain.com/website-2/
- if end-user visits domain.com/main/?showads=yes —> serve website as domain.com/website-1/
- İf end-user visits domain domain.com/main/ —> serve website as domain.com/website-2/

**Note:** this is not a redirection question, I just want to serve with the same URL.

**p.s.** I’m running a WordPress website on an Apache server.

I’m open to any solution via PHP, WordPress, or Apache (.htaccess) config.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a condition to evaluate the query string:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)showads=yes(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /website-1/$1 [END]

RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /website-2/$1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Hey @arkascha, thanks a lot for detailed answer. I have option to edit "apache.conf" - did you intend to say that?

Comment: The layout of the configuration of the apache http server depends on the distribution you are using. Different strategies. Sometimes a file called "apache.conf" is part of that, yes. You should try to understand the difference between that configuration and the distributed configuration files (".htaccess" style files).